# PHP7 install: libcurl3 and libwebp5 are depends, but not installable

Tags: nginx, libcurl, raspbian, apt-get, php-7.0

I'm trying to run the following command in order to set up a web server on my Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian.

`sudo apt-get install nginx php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl php7.0-xml php7.0-json php7.0-zip php7.0-mb php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-gd`

When I run this, at the end of the output, I get the message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependedencies:
  php7.0-curl : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.18.0) but it is not installable
  php7.0-gd : Depends: libwebp5 but it is not installable
```

I've done a lot of searching and found that I do, in fact, have *libcurl4* installed but I'm not able to figure much out.  I've done `sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` before trying to install.

Any help is much appreciated; I've tried a fair amount to figure this out on my own and have done a ton of searching (hopefully enough to where somebody doesn't link me a thread that answers my exact question), so I'm hoping for a little bit of help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: php7.0 is not supported at least for one year already.
Do you really need 7.0? Have you tried newer versions?

Comment: I tried 'sudo apt-get install php' and it installed (I believe) PHP7.4.  When trying the above command but with php7.4 rather than php7.0 prefixes it shows "E: Unable to locate package php7.4-mcrypt / Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-mcrypt' / Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-mcrypt'.  I assume this means I should add to/change my sources?